# Golang go get failed with git ls-remote -q using the wrong url @ Go 1.13

Tags: go, go-modules

## **Ok according to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34094, go 1.13.3 fixed this problem**

Env: Go 1.13, Windows

I got a fresh copy of Go on a Windows machine and try to build my project here.

However, the mod which used to work is failing right now:

```
C:\xxx> go get -v private.repo.com/dir/utils.git
get "private.repo.com/dirxxxx": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"private.repo.com/dirxxxx", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx.git"} at //private.repo.com/dirxxxx?go-get=1
get "private.repo.com": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"private.repo.com", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://private.repo.com.git"} at //private.repo.com/?go-get=1
go: finding private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git v0.0.5
go: downloading private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git v0.0.5
go: extracting private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git v0.0.5
go get private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git: git ls-remote -q https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx.git in C:\Users\admin\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\227f0870299637a3fadb469f608679095de39005c860e3949d82a547e8c30143: exit status 128:
        GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

Which is, well, not wrong since there is indeed no https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx.git.

What we have is a https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git. How can I force go git to use a certain tag or skip the ls-remote since it already found a version and extracting the files lol

---

I config GOPROXY=direct according to https://golang.org/doc/go1.13, since I am using a private repo.

And also set proxy & stuff following the guide but problems remain.

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like the problem re-occur in go 1.13: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34094

Answer (score 0):

### Aliasing

If you have moved your repository from `https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx.git` to `https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git`, you can use the [replace directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) in your `go.mod` file to define alias paths:

```
replace private.repo.com/dirxxxx => private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils v0.0.5
```

This way, when you run `go get private.repo.com/dirxxxx`, it will fetch from `https://private.repo.com/dirxxxx/utils.git` instead.

### HTTPS Authentication

And if your repository is password protected, you can config your `git` with the username and password like this:

```
git config --global url."https://username:password@private.repo.com/".insteadOf "https://private.repo.com/"
```

Which generates a section in your `~/.gitconfig` like this:

```
[url "https://username:password@private.repo.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://private.repo.com/
```

Comment: Thx for the comment, the replace workaround sound nice, will try that out.
but there are too many repo in the project, wonder if that can be done in a wildcard style

Answer (score 0):

In my case, maybe it was related to my case-sensitive macOS file system.

I had a folder `tokenApi`, but the package name was `tokenapi`.

When I imported it using `internal/handlers/tokenapi`, I got the above error. Changing it to `internal/handlers/tokenApi` fixed the error.